# Can't override checkbox style using crispy forms

Tags: css, django, checkbox, django-crispy-forms

While creating forms for my app I had to make a custom checkbox (I am terrible with css so this was not easy). I got it to work and it looks like this when I create the form manually:

[image: Styled checkbox]

The manual `html` is

```
<div class="checkbox icheck-primary">
   {{ form.active }}
   <label for="id_active">Active</label>
</div>
```

But when using the `wrapper_class` attribute on a crispy forms `Field` it displays as standard:

[image: Non styled checkbox]

And the `crispy forms` code:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Fieldset(
            'Add Contact',
            'first_name',
            Field('active', wrapper_class='icheck-primary', css_class='icheck-primary')
        ))
```

I tried using a custom `Div` template but I couldn't get it to work. In the docs all I could find was the `wrapper_class`.

Am I missing something simple or could someone point me in the right direction?

[Edit]
`HTML` output from `crispy_forms`:

```
<div id="div_id_active" class="checkbox icheck-primary">
    <label for="id_active" class=""> 
    <input name="active" class="checkboxinput" id="id_active" checked="" type="checkbox">
         Active
    </label> 
</div>
```

And here is my manual/forms generated `html`

```
<div class="checkbox icheck-primary">
    <input name="stay_logged_in" class="checkbox icheck-primary" id="id_stay_logged_in" type="checkbox">
    <label for="id_stay_logged_in">Remember me</label>
</div>
```

[Edit 2] This is a sample of the `css selectors`

```
.radio > input[type="radio"]:first-child:checked + label::before,
.checkbox > input[type="checkbox"]:first-child:checked + label::before,
.radio > input[type="radio"]:first-child:checked + input[type="hidden"] + label::before,
.checkbox > input[type="checkbox"]:first-child:checked + input[type="hidden"] + label::before {
    content: "\e013";
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #b4aba1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    line-height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #b4aba1;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    background-color: #0060a1 !important;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -29px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide html and css, thanks.

Comment: Updated the question, thanks!

Comment: What is the HTML that gets generated by crispy? What does the CSS look like? Have you tried using an inspector? It looks like the CSS selector isn't matching the input.

Comment: @dirn that is exactly right. The problem is how to get `crispy_forms` to match it. I'll add the html to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @dirn would I be right in thinking it might be because the label wraps the input in `crispy_forms`?

Comment: The reason @ovokuro and I asked for the CSS is that without it (at least the relevant selectors), it's impossible to tell what needs to be changed. If the CSS is selecting by `id`, that needs to change. If it's selecting based on HTML and `class`, then a couple of different changes would address the issue. Please share the relevant CSS selectors.

Comment: @dirn Sorry, I don't know how to get the selectors from the crispy forms code. (I have only the most basic understanding of css. I avoid it when possible.)

Comment: @dirn usually I just assign the class to the surrounding `div` and that is that.

Comment: The selectors have nothing to do with crispy. They are part of the CSS. You need to share some of that or it's going to be impossible for us to tell you why the CSS isn't being applied. Besides, avoiding CSS isn't going to help your understanding.

Comment: @dirn I meant I usually avoid it as I am not a front-end developer. How do I get the selectors? As I said, I only ever add the class to whatever element I need. And thank you, I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: Okay, so that sounds like the selector is something like `.icheck-primary > input[type=checkbox]`. If that's more or less correct, the `>` is the important part for your question.

Comment: Now I know what you mean. I'll update the question in a minute. Thank you!

Comment: Updated the question with a sample of the selectors. This is where I made my changes to the css.

Comment: It looks like your problem is that crispy places the `input` inside the `label` and your CSS wants the latter to proceed the former. You may need to [use a custom layout](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for that.

Comment: @dirn thanks. I was trying that and wasn't able to sort it. I'll have another go at it. If you add this as the answer I'll accept it. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @dirn I got it to work. Thank you very much. I will post my code as the answer as soon as I get the chance.

Comment: Awesome! Good job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some help in the comments from @dirn I went back and made a custom template.

Since all of my checkboxes should look this same I created a `checkboxinput_template` based on the existing `crispy_forms` templates:

```
    {% load crispy_forms_field %}

    <div id="div_{{ field.auto_id }}" class="checkbox icheck-primary {% if form_show_errors and field.errors %} error{% endif %}{% if field.css_classes %} {{ field.css_classes }}{% endif %}">
        {{ field }}
        <label class="control-label {{ label_class }}" for="id_{{ field.html_name }}">{{ field.label|safe }}{% if field.field.required %}<span class="asteriskField">*</span>{% endif %}</label>
        <div class="controls {{ field_class }}">
            {% include 'bootstrap3/layout/help_text.html' %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

I added the `icheck-primary` class to the surrounding `div` and moved the field itself out of the label tag. This allowed the selectors to work properly.

I think this could also be done by overriding the `fields.html` but for the moment this solves my problem.

This is probably not the best solution and I'd appreciate it if anyone could share a better one.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with django-crispy-forms, but use django-widget-tweaks for adding css to django forms. You only need to adjust templates, no python code. Makes it a lot easier and you keep styling separate from code.

Comment: I did look at widget-tweaks but since I am not very good at css etc. I decided to go with crispy. If I can't sort it I will check it out though. Thanks =)

Comment: But I assume the only thing you need to do is to add the 'icheck-primary' css class to your input, right? Could you paste the html you want rendered as well?

Comment: For this one thing, yes, but crispy forms offers a lot of flexibility that I make use of for other parts.

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid alright, I hope you can figure it out!

Comment: cheers! If I don't sort it out by the end of the week I'll come back, if you add a little code showing how to do it I can mark this as the answer =)